# pandas to_datetime gets different years with parameter #format or not

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, format

Without format param:

```
pd.to_datetime(1)
```

output:

```
Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001')
```

With format param:

```
pd.to_datetime(1, format="%H")
```

output:

```
Timestamp('1900-01-01 01:00:00')
```

The first output year is 1970, while the 2nd output is 1900.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if you pass a format string to the `format` parameter, `pandas.to_datetime()` will follow the Python standard strftime and strptime behavior. Please see Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

It says

> For the `datetime.strptime()` class method, the default value is 1900-01-01T00:00:00.000: any components not specified in the format string will be pulled from the default value.

`format` parameter has `None` as its default value, and the `origin` parameter takes `'unix'` as its default value. When you leave these two parameters as default, the origin is set to 1970-01-01.